# iTunes reject App Store Icon in tvOS 11 and Xcode 9

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos, xcode9, application-loader

I faced with a problem in Xcode 9 (works fine in Xcode 8 before).
I can't upload tvOS build because of incorrect image asset for App Store icon.
But App Store icons have exactly 1280x768 size and 3 layers.
I was able to upload build to iTunes before with Xcode 8.
But now I receive such error:

> ERROR ITMS-90718: "Invalid Image Asset. The App Store Icon must only
>   contain an image with size (1280pt × 768pt @1x). Refer to
>   https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon
>   for more information"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you happen to have also 2x version of your assets in the Xcode? I had this same issue than you and I was somehow presuming that I would need to provide also 2x version, but once I removed that and only have the 1x, the upload succeeded!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Needed only 1x for the "App Icon - Large" and 1x and 2x for the other "App Icon - Small"

Comment: I had struggled with same issue for 5 hours. Worked for me.
Remove All "App Icon - Large" 2x.
Need "App Icon - Large 1x" and "App Icon - Small 1x, 2x".

Comment: When I have added image group with "New tvOS App Icon and Top Shelf Image" in xcode assets. I have got the folder with name "Brand Assets", inside that there are two images. 1 - App Icon - App Store and 2- App Icon. Can you please explain with the proper structure. which one helped you and which one not ?

Comment: Wanted to add a quick follow up to this - the asset catalog template provided by Xcode 9 includes two Image Stack Layers for app icons: "App Icon - App Store" and "App Icon". You should only provide 1x for the "App Store" iteration, and both 1x and 2x for the other one. I just wasted way too much time on this label change by Apple.

Comment: Everytime when I release new version of my game (with Unity) I have some trouble like this with xcode. I understand that sometimes bug happen, but it is everytime (ok 8 from 10)! Thank god for forum and good guys with solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was providing x2 versions for App Icon Small, Top Shelf Image, Top Shelf Image Wide, **but NOT** for App Icon Large. Can't understand what Apple are doing with this.

Answer (score 2):

I also added a 2x version of the icon. And had the same error. Deleting the 2x version helped. It works ;-)

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps me. I figured that in tvOS guidelines there is only mention about @1x icon

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I hadn't added 2x images. After adding 2x images, this issue was fixed.